# Redirect to edit page if id is present in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to redirect a page, I want to check if params student_id and pre_writings table's student_id match and if it matches the I want to redirect it to edit page.

my pre-writings schema:

```
create_table "pre_writings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "student_id"
    t.integer "classroom_id"
    t.integer "task_id"
    t.text "q1"
    t.string "q1answer"
    t.text "q2"
    t.string "q2answer"
    t.text "q3"
    t.string "q3answer"
    t.text "q4"
    t.string "q4answer"
    t.text "q5"
    t.string "q5answer"
    t.text "q6"
    t.string "q6answer"
    t.text "q7"
    t.string "q7answer"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

And the link I am sending the params with student_id

```
<a href="/<%= @tasksname.downcase %>/new?student_id=<%= student_id=element.id %>&task_id=<%= assessment.task.id %>  ">
```

Comment: What's your actual question here? Why aren't you using `link_to` and your route helpers?

Comment: I edited the question I want to check if params student_id and pre_writings table's student_id match and if it matches the i want to redirect it to edit page. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you're using Rails best practices here. It should be simple if you were. Can you share your models and their associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the appropriate method in your controller, add:

```
redirect_to <your edit page path> if params[:student_id].present?
```

However, I would like to echo what other commenters have said, I do not think you are following Rails best practices.  If you follow the "Rails Way" of doing things, this should be easier.  We will need more information about your model setup and what you are trying to do to help you refactor your code to follow Rails best practices.